# Memoizable functions - Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-function

When querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` or `SHOW FUNCTION` we could find a column `IS_MEMOIZABLE`.

```
SELECT IS_MEMOIZABLE, *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FUNCTIONS;
```

None of built-in function is memoizable:

```
SHOW BUILTIN FUNCTIONS;

SELECT "is_memoizable", *
FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))
WHERE "is_memoizable" <> 'N';
-- 0 rows
```

> [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)
>
> In computing, memoization or memoisation is an optimization technique used primarily to speed up computer programs by storing the results of expensive function calls and returning the cached result when the same inputs occur again.

The question is how to create user defined function that has `IS_MEMOIZABLE` property equals to 'Y'(true)?

Is there any specific keyword required and/or does it apply to specific types of functions(external/Python/Java/immutable/...)?

Comment: assuming you saw this https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/functions-is-memoizable ?

Comment: @AdrianWhite Yes, I've seen it. Unfrotunately it does not provide any answers for questions asked here.

Comment: Not even the "the bundle is disabled by default" part?

Comment: @AdrianWhite `SELECT CURRENT_VERSION(), SYSTEM$BEHAVIOR_CHANGE_BUNDLE_STATUS('2022_08');
-- 7.3.0 ENABLED`

Comment: I wrote some notes https://hoffa.medium.com/faster-snowflake-udfs-and-policies-with-memoizable-b84544c1bf5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Memoizable UDFs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql-scalar-functions.html#label-udf-sql-scalar-memoizable)

> **A scalar SQL UDF can be memoizable.** A memoizable function caches the result of calling a scalar SQL UDF and then returns the cached result when the output is needed at a later time. The benefit of using a memoizable function is to improve performance for complex queries, such as multiple column lookups in mapping tables referenced within a row access policy or masking policy.
>
> You can define a scalar SQL UDF to be memoizable in the CREATE FUNCTION statement by specifying the `MEMOIZABLE` keyword. **Memoizable functions do not include arguments.**

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
RETURNS INT
MEMOIZABLE
AS
$$SELECT 1$$;
```

Comment: I wrote some notes https://hoffa.medium.com/faster-snowflake-udfs-and-policies-with-memoizable-b84544c1bf5